# Write a function that returns the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number

Tags: python, function, count

e.g `count_primes(100) --> 25`

```
def count_primes(num):
    for n in range(2,num+1):
        prime=True
        for i in range(2,n):
            if(n%i == 0):
                prime=False
        if prime:
            print(n)
```

But I didn't know how to count the numbers.It just prints the prime numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Increment a counter variable instead of printing the numbers.

You also can stop looping once you find a divisor, so use `break` after setting `prime = False`

```
def count_primes(num):
    counter = 0
    for n in range(2,num+1):
        prime=True
        for i in range(2,n):
            if(n%i == 0):
                prime=False
                break
        if prime:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: Thank you.It was useful.

Comment: Note: For needle in haystack problems like this, you don't need a flag value like `prime`. Just remove all lines using `prime`, and replace `if prime:` with `else:`, with the `counter += 1` only executing if the `for` loop exits by running to completion (meaning `n` is prime), and not if it `break`s (because some number divided `n`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I didn't feel the need to teach that extra Python feature, the algorithm is what's important.

Comment: @Barmar: Sure. Not saying it needs to be there, just pointing out that this is the canonical case for the `for`/`else` construct: Simplifying the needle in a haystack problem (where the "has needle case" is handled inside the loop, when the needle is identified, just before the `break`, while the "no needle" case is tacked on in the `for`'s `else` block. You don't need to teach it, but it's good for new Python programmers to become familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with lambdas, reduce and filter functions, here's a way to do it in one line:

```py
count_primes = lambda x : len(reduce(lambda acc, y: list(filter(lambda z: (z==y) or (z % y != 0), acc)), [i for i in range(2, x+1)], [i for i in range(2, x+1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an array and at the end just count the length of the array

```
def count_prime(num):
    arr=[2]
    for n in range(3,num+1):
        prime=True
        for i in arr:
            if(n%i == 0):
                prime=False
        if prime:
            arr.append(n)
    print (arr)
    return len(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Count primes: Write a function that returns the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number
e.g count_primes(100) --> 25

```
def count_prime(num):
# Check for 0 and 1 input
if num < 2:
    return 0

# 2 or Greater
# list to store our prime number
primes = [2]

#Counter going up to the input num
x = 3

while x<=num:
    for y in range(3,x,2):
        if x%y == 0:
            x += 2
            break
    else:
        primes.append(x)
        x += 2
print(primes)
return len(primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def num_check(num):
    
    primes=[]
    if num < 2:
        return 0
        
   
    for num in range(num+1):
        if num>1:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if (num%i)==0:
                    break
            else:
                primes.append(num)
    print(primes)
    return len(primes)
```

Comment: Only code does not say anything. Please, explain the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_primes(num):
    key=0
    for i in range(3,num):
        flag=0
        for k in range(2,i):
            if(i%k==0):
                flag+=1
            else:
                pass
        if (flag==0):
            key+=1
    return key+1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from sympy import isprime

def count_primes(num):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, num):
        if isprime(i):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: These "write a function that" assignments usually mean you have to write all the code by yourself, not use a library.